# Make Trait protected attributes accessible to Eloquent in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits

I'm new to using Traits and having trouble saving the protected attributes of my trait within my eloquent model:

Here is my Route model:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent;

class Route extends Eloquent {

    use CardTrait {
        CardTrait::__construct as __CardConstruct;
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'routes';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $visible = [
        'name',
        'description'
    ];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
        $this->__CardConstruct($attributes);
    }
    //relationships follow
}
```

and here is the CardTrait trait:

```
namespace App\Models;

trait CardTrait {

    protected $timesAsked;
    protected $factor;
    protected $nextTime;

    public function __construct($attributes = array(), $timesAsked = 0, $factor = 2.5, $nextTime = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        if (is_null($nextTime)) $nextTime = \Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $this->factor = $factor;
        $this->nextTime = $nextTime;
        $this->timesAsked = $timesAsked;

        public function answer($difficulty)
        {
            if($difficulty < 3)
                $this->timesAsked = 1;
        }
        //other methods follow
}
```

In my controller I can use:

```
$route = new Route();
$route->name = "New Name";
$route->description = "New Description";
$route->answer(5);
$route->save();
```

`name` and `description` save fine, and although I have columns for `timesAsked`, `factor` and `nextTime` When I dd($route) I can see

```
protected 'timesAsked' => int 1
protected 'factor' => float 2.6
protected 'nextTime' => string '2015-04-15 21:36:53' (length=19)
```

so I know the methods of the Trait are working fine.

My question is how can I save these values with Eloquent so that these can be stored and retrieved from the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent will store values in an internal attributes array. This is what is actually written to the database. It will not write values to the attributes array if they already exist as a data member on the model. Look into the [__set and __get](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic methods and how they are used in [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3022)

So long story short, remove the protected data members from the model.